# "Кракозябры" в Android Studio

Tags: windows, android-studio, шрифты, реестр

Изменил системный шрифт в реестре, везде все нормально кроме Android Studio.

Как исправлять?

[image: Скриншот Android Studio]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шрифт имеет смысл ставить тот, который в системе установлен, желательно `monospace`:

**`File` ⇒ `Settings` ⇒ `Appearance & Behavior` ⇒ `Appearance`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И кодировку нормальную тоже можно поставить заодно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]